# Order of the curve and generator

Tags: elliptic-curves, group-theory, elliptic-curve-generation, prime-field

Does the order of the curve and the order of generator should be coprime for an elliptic curve defined over a prime field?

Answer (score 1):

The order of any point is a divisor of the curve group order, hence they are never coprime, unless your "generator" is the point at infinity.

This follows from
**Lagrange's theorem:** If $H$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$, then $\lvert H\rvert$ divides $\lvert G\rvert$.